# Multiple XMLs to PDF: best approach

Tags: xml, pdf, pdf-generation

I have some XML files which are used to generate my webpages, however I need to be able to allow the user to select a number of pages then combine them into one PDF. This PDF needs to have different styling to the actual web page (the content is kept in XML files ;) ).

p.s. the PDF must have table of contents... and will include images taken from the website.

Comment: About "CSS+XHTML to PDF" technologies, see [Why use XSL-FO instead of CSS2, for transform HTML into good PDF?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10641667/287948)
question and answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would use a library like iText or [iTextSharp](http://itextsharp.sourceforge.net/) to build a PDF using your content.

Comment: iText/iTextSharp are AGPL-ed. so, they are free _if you are ready to open source your application_.

Answer (score 2):

Write an XSLT stylesheet which transforms your XML files to [XSL-FO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSL_Formatting_Objects) and then use an XSL-FO implementation (e.g. [Apache FOP](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/)) to produce PDF.

Comment: do you know any good references for this because all the sources I found where out of date and not comprehensive

Answer (score 1):

I use [Prince](http://princexml.com/) in my product.  It's not cheap (neither is my product), but it's extremely easy to use, and very fast.